# What's wrong with these windows

Tags: windows

I've got several windows in my house, built in 2008, which appear to have streaks. These are double-pane windows, however I've seen double-panes with a broken seal, and this doesn't appear to be the same thing. It's not "foggy", instead it looks like somebody smeared grease on the window. I have risked my life to hang out of a second story window to try to clean off the outside, only to discover that the opaque portion is between the glass panes. Could this be some sort of failure of low-E glass, or is this just a strange presentation of a broken seal?

I'm assuming the only way to make the glass clear is to replace it, but I can't be sure since I don't know what the problem is.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can see it on the bottom one and the term smile comes to memory for failed seals as the moisture that gets in creates a smile on the glass and it is most visible with cold weather as the humidity condenses on the cold plate of glass.

Comment: This streaking NEVER changes at all with weather or over time. They've all looked identical to this every day for the last four years.

Comment: My first guess would be a manufacturing defect (maybe someone smudged some adhesive on the inner pane and didn't properly remove it), so I'm curious if the previous owners also have seen these streaks (since 2008)?

Comment: How long have you owned the home?

Comment: I’ve been here four years. I like the adhesive explanation, except that I have the problem on four separate windows and one door.

Comment: A door? Do you have photos of that one? It's very strange at any rate, anything on the *inside* of a double glass panel had to have happened during manufacturing, i.e. in the factory. Different place than wherever the door comes from.

Comment: Added two pictures of the door

Comment: Ah, the door also has glazing! Very unusual to see the same defect in different products. Perhaps both elements were from the same supplier then. If the streaks are inside the double glazing panels in all cases, and they do not change their properties (opacity, size etc) during the day and the year, I can't think of any other way for them to have appeared there other than during manufacturing.